# Windows key and backspace stopped working on laptop

Tags: keyboard, bios, hardware-detection

A few days ago, while using my laptop normally, the backspace key and the windows key stopped working.

I did *all* the checks suggested by the first results of the few results of the main search engines.

Apparently, it seems that's not a OS-level software problem. Also when lunching the bios, in the diagnosis software, i cannot detect any key pressed for the "windows key" and "backspace key". As expected, also when booting on linux, the same keys are not working.

Any idea on how to find the problem? I don't think it's a hardware issues as the keyboard (and the laptop) is quite new and the problem happened at the same time.

With an external keyboard my PC is able to recognize the right keystrokes..

Thank you!

Comment: All your tests would indicate is **is** a hardware issue. If it's quite new, check your warranty status.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the laptop is new doesn't rule out a potential hardware issue at all, and everything you have mentioned so far almost definitely indicates a hardware issue. Manufacturing defects are a rampant problem, this is why warranties exist.

As you claim the laptop is 'quite new', the keyboard should be covered by warranty. The best approach would be to consult your manufacturer for a solution.